# How do I show a list and hide it after a specific time without using GUI in python?

Tags: python

How do I show a list and hide it after a specific time without using **GUI** in python?

Let's take `list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']` as my list.

I want to show this list to user and after 8 seconds hide this from user.

Comment: Technolgy used, OS and code maybe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:-

```
import time

l = [10, 20, 30, 40]
print(l, end="")
time.sleep(8)
print('\r ')
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

**OUTPUT AFTER 8 SECONDS:-**

```
# empty console screen
```

**NOTE:-** The behavious of `\r` escape sequence is different on different environments (ide's/line-by-line interpreters) so you may get the desired result, or you may get something like `10, 20, 30, 40]` where only the first character of the console is hidden, so you can get through that by applying multiple spaces after `\r`.

Comment: thank you, sir. but this when I run this code in python IDEL, the list didn't disappear.

Comment: @Yasas As i mentioned in the NOTE, the behavior of `\r` changes at different environments. IDLE as you mentioned is a line by line interpreter therefore the changes may not be noticable there, In order to make it work, run the `.py` file created by IDLE using command prompt (if you are on windows)